# Accessing Javascript Array without using [] Brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write some javascript in an environment where square brackets are used for macro replacement, so they can't be used as normal in the script.

If I create an array as an object with `new Array()` I can use push() and pop() to access the elements, but for native arrays I can't figure out a way to get to the elements without using brackets. For example, the array returned from:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Is there a way to assign a native array into an Array object so I can use push() and pop(), or is there another way to get inside?

Comment: Is there no way of escaping the square brackets from the macro environment? That seems like the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: Where are these marco replacements going to be?  Will the be inside of externally included javascript files?

Comment: This for an HTML report generator that really wasn't designed for hacking in this Javascript. I also just found that it's replacing `|` with `~` in my RegExp's... sigh. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `NodeList` collections you can use `.item()`:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var firstItem = allElements.item(0);
```

Source: [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList)

Answer (score 6):

yes, you can use prototype and slice method for example (Does not work in IE):

```
var index = 1;
Array.prototype.slice.call(allElements,index,index+1);
```

For IE, the only way I can think of is to copy all elements from collection to the array:

```
var newarr = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<allElements.length;i++){
    newarr.push(allElements[i]);
}
```

Or, you can use this function (Works in IE and Firefox):

```
window.atIndex = function(array,index){
    return eval("array" + String.fromCharCode(91) + String(index) + String.fromCharCode(93));
}
```

Get any item by using `atIndex(allElements,0);`

Comment: No go in IE, sorry. "Error: JScript object expected"

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]; //just a dummy array, I assume you don't use square brackets to assign an array in your code
el0 = arr.slice(0,1).pop(); //returns 0th element
el1 = arr.slice(1,2).pop(); //returns 1st element
...
```

Don't have IE here, but it works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the JavaScript engine will convert literals to objects for you (it does this behind the scenes)

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
alert( arr.pop() );
```

Secondly, understand that the return value from `document.getElementsByTagName()` *is not* an array.  It's an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/HTMLCollection).

Comment: Voted down?  *Really?*.  Sigh.

Comment: While it provides accurate information, this answer misses the point of avoiding [] brackets (and therefore does not seem useful in answering the question).

Comment: No it doesn't.  I clearly showed how you can use array object methods on array literals.  I just *also* noted that the return value of `document.getElementsByTagName()` is not an array, so those methods won't work anyway.

Comment: Not to mention that I linked to the documentation for HTMLCollection which clearly shows the methods available.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it's returning an HTMLCollection - that does help!

Answer (score 1):

You could define a macro that inserts the [] braces. This might be possible. :-)

However, I am wondering why you still use this environment - even Notepad might be more comfortable then.

Answer (score -1):

for loops you can iterate through the collection like
`for(var item in array){

doStuff(item);

}`

You could also use Jquery's makeArray function
`var newArray = $.makeArray(array);`

I'm assuming you have no choice in your environment square braces are a normal thing in tons of programming languages. The ideal solution is use an environment that doesn't limit your programming